# Make data files record undeletable in Odoo

Tags: database, odoo, data-files

I want to load data files with existing records in odoo and I want to prevent the user from deleting it

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way to do it, but you can do this solution:

1- add a field "no_delete".

2- In your data file, set it to "True":

```
<field name="no_delete">1</field>
```

3-Create a record rule with this domain:

```
<field name="domain_force">[('no_delete','=',True)]</field>
```

and set delete to false:

```
<field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"/>
```